# Update column - remove first and last characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a successful `SELECT` statement to both show me all the company names that are surrounded by double quotes like "ABC Company" for example. I want to permanently remove the double quotes and replace the company name with the cleaned version.

Here is my `SELECT` that works great:

```
SELECT
    companyname,
    CASE
       WHEN companyname LIKE '"%"' 
          THEN SUBSTRING(companyname, 2, LEN(companyname) - 2)
       ELSE companyname
    END AS CC
FROM 
    Company_Table 
WHERE 
    companyName LIKE '"%"'
```

I am having trouble converting this statement to an `UPDATE`. I want to affect the original `companyname` column in place.

I have tried to add `UPDATE` clauses around the above code, but I just cannot seem to get it right.

Can I please get an example of how I can remove the first and last chars of a column in place.

Otherwise, it is manual labor!

I expect that the original companyname field will be devoid of "".

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to string handling many products have their own functions.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) For example, one trailing double quote, but no leading, two leading etc.

Comment: One of the few times where a dbms tag isn't needed I'd say; given a simple working select it can be converted to a working update without knowing the specific db vendor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an update:

```
UPDATE Company_Table 
SET companyname = SUBSTRING(companyname, 2, LEN(companyname)-2)
WHERE companyName like '"%"'
```

Single table update queries take the form

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 ...
WHERE truth_test
```

You can use the same column names on the left and the right of the = in the SET. All the right hand sides are worked out then applied to the lefts so the values don't interfere with each other

(if you were to say SET a = a + 1, b = a + 1 then for a row where both a and b started out as 0, they would both be 1 after the update. The a doesn't increment from 0 to 1 then the b become 1+1. In other words, b is set to old-a + 1 not new-a + 1

Comment: This worked great! I overly complicated it, tried to wrap the update around the case statement, when all I needed was the condition. Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, the ELSE won't actually ever fire,  because the WHERE guarantees that the only rows the CASE even sees are those surrounded by " ". (The WHERE is processed before the select, the WHEN is always true)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you don't have double quotes anywhere but the beginning and end of your companyName values you could use the [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to replace them with an empty string.

```
UPDATE Company_Table 
SET companyname = REPLACE(companyname, '"', '')
WHERE companyName like '"%"'
```

Note that the second parameter is a double quote surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any chance of a malformed input you need to avoid a negative length argument:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(companyname) > 2
     THEN SUBSTRING(companyname, 2, LEN(companyname) - 2)
     ELSE '' END;
```